# In Confluence, how to make a template with predefined values such as document owner or current date?

Tags: confluence

By looking in the default meeting notes template, I see variables such as `$currentDateLozenge` or `$documentOwner`. And it creates pages with the current date and my name as expected. But when I copy/paste this template in a custom template, these variables react like any other variable by prompting for values.

What do I miss?

Comment: Note that there's apparently a solution based on [user macros](https://superuser.com/questions/1436741/how-to-auto-insert-current-user-name-in-confluence), but [it requires System Administrator permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/writing-user-macros-4485.html) (which in my case I don't have).